# Symfony Doctrine Sluggable to swap slug between two objects with the same slug set

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, slug

I have multiple objects with the same slug set that needs to be unique.

Like the following

- Object id:1  slug:   object
- Object id:2  slug:   object-1
- Object id:3  slug:   object-2
- Object id:4  slug:   object-3

From the database entries like above, I'd like to "swap"  slug between 2 objects.

For example,

- Object id:1  slug:   object-2
- Object id:2  slug:   object-1
- Object id:3  slug:   object
- Object id:4  slug:   object-3

I have tried the below logic:

1. Set Object1 to have 'random' slug and persist then flush (so that Object3 can take the 'main' slug)
2. Set Object3 to have 'object' slug and persist then flush

   **(At this point, Object3 recieves 'object-2' slug as if the Object1 has the main slug, object.)**

   (Above works when there are only 2 objects)
3. Set Object1 to have NULL slug to get auto generated slug

Any advice will be so much appreciated! if anything not clear enough, please leave a comment!

```
$product = $em->getRepository('EronkaCoreBundle:Product')->find($id);

    $mainProduct = $em->getRepository('EronkaCoreBundle:Product')->findProductsByVersion($product->getProductKey(), true);
    $mainProduct = $mainProduct[0];

    $mainSlug=$mainProduct->getSlug();
    $versionSlug=$product->getSlug();

    $mainProduct->setSlug('temporarySlug');

    // Persist temporary slug to be able to swap
    $mainProduct->setIsMain(false);
    $em->persist($mainProduct);
    $em->flush();

// At this point, no object has the main slug 'object'

    // give proper main slug to the selected product

    $product->setSlug($mainSlug);
    $product->setIsMain(true);
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    // Product slug not set as proper slug =(, it gets 'object2' slug as if the main slug 'object' was not available.


    // reset the slug
    $mainProduct->setSlug(NULL);
    $em->flush();
```

Comment: you said that you tried that logic, what is the result you got? It worked and you're asking if there is any alternative? If it did not work you should specify the result. Can you also show the code?

Comment: Hi Filo, as you can see in bold text, when the object that should get the main slug 'object', automatically signed with 'object-2' although the object1 no longer has the main slug 'object'.  Ill share code soon

Comment: Code shared and again,  the code above works fine only when there are 2 objects ('object' and 'object-1' slugs)